# How to list all running mongod processes?

Tags: mongodb

Does `mongod` have a cli command similar to `forever list` that will show all running `mongod` processes?

In `mongod --help` I could only find `--shutdown` option:

> --shutdown kill a running server (for init scripts)

Ok, we can terminate a running server. But how may we see running servers?

Answer (score 0):

In Git Bash:

```
$ ps -alW | grep mongod
4592 0 0 4592 ? 0 12:47:09 C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe
```

This is a OS way using `ps`. Still do not know if `mongod` has special command for that.

Also here https://askubuntu.com/questions/182137/how-do-i-know-which-processes-are-running-and-who-own-the-process

Comment: Mongod [creates a `pid` file](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#processManagement.pidFilePath) for each instance. `--shutdown` uses this to track which process id to stop. So one approach is to track all configurations that the processes start with, and simply check pid files existence.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [mongostat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/)